Не удается регулировать степень jpeg-сжатия в выходных pdf, создаваемых Ghostscript
Конвертирую pdf-файлы в формат pdf/a с помощью Ghostscript. Использую опции -dColorImageFilter=/DCTEncode и -dGrayImageFilter=/DCTEncode. На выходе получаю pdf/a с jpeg-сжатием. Мне необходимо явно указывать нужную мне степень компрессии. Фильтр DCTEncode, насколько я знаю, по умолчанию должен использовать сжатие 75 %; я хочу произвольно регулировать это значение. Пробовал опции -dJPEGQ и -dQFactor (https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.03.0/Devices.html#id1), но они никак не влияют на результат: pdf/a при любых их значениях получается одинакового размера и с компрессией изображений 58 %.
Опишу, что и как делаю:

на входе — pdf, содержащий одно изображение tiff с lzw-сжатием (rgb, 24 bit),
Ghostscript 10.02.1 (пробовал и более раннюю версию),
степень полученной компрессии проверяю программой PDFPageSelect (https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=23:47259),
собственно, команда: gswin64c.exe -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dJPEGQ=80 -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -dColorImageFilter=/DCTEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/DCTEncode -sOutputFile=out_pdf_a.pdf in_pdf.pdf


Всё, что удалось выяснить по теме: если исходный pdf содержит jpeg-изображения, фильтр DCTEncode по умолчанию оставляет их без изменений, повторно не сжимает.
